# sharing class variable between async method and normal return method

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

here is my class, have a async method and get method

```
class Webservice
{
    public string token;
    public async void login (string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
        string username = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["email"];
        string password = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"];

        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
        });

        // Get the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

        // Get the response content.
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        // Get the stream of the content.
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            // Write the output.
            //Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            token = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        }
    }


    public string getToken (string url)
    {
        this.login(url);
        Console.WriteLine(token);
        return token+"abc";
    }
```

the token = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); can't set the class variable or maybe set after getToken was returned, anyone know how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Don't use an `async void`, it's bad practice, use `async Task`. I think you want to make `token` static, so `public static string token;`. I'm guessing, because you haven't said what error message you get or where it occurs...

Comment: Why login is async? As I see, you want the result immediately after login.

Comment: `async void` is only meant for event handlers. It can't be awaited which means you have no way of knowing if the method completed at all. *Instead* of setting a field (which is very bad practice) change the signature to `async Task<string>` and return the token. Then you can easily write `var token=await login(url);` and do anything you want with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling:

```
this.login(url);
```

You are firing and forgetting the async call.

You need to make the containing function async and await the `login` call to finish

```
public async Task<string> getToken (string url)
{
    await this.login(url);
    Console.WriteLine(token);
    return token+"abc";
}
```

**Do not** use `this.login(url).Wait()`.

Finally

```
public async void login (string url)
```

`async void` is used for event handlers, it should be this:

```
public async Task login (string url)
```

### IMHO

I believe this class has a too many responsibilities. It shouldn't be used to retrieve and store the token. One would assume you have some kind of caching layer in your application (it could just be memory).

Therefore, I would prefer logic like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.cache[TOKEN_KEY])) {
   this.cache[TOKEN_KEY] = await this.webservice.login(url);
}

// use the this.cache[TOKEN_KEY] here...
await this.anotherService.MakeRequest(this.cache[TOKEN_KEY]);
```

The `cache` could just be a singleton class with a dictionary...

The new `Task<string> login(string url)` method would now return the token at the bottom, rather than just setting a private field:

```
return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This logic would then make it easier for you to add layers in and around the login if needs be without making the code hard to reason about.

Comment: thanks, but do you know how to get the task<string> value?             Webservice ws = new Webservice();
            Task<string> token = ws.getToken("http://localhost/m1/m1apiserver/public/api/login");
            Console.WriteLine(token); it will return "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

Comment: @hkguile the same way you got the result from `ReadToEndAsync`, you need to await the function. If you are going to use async/await you need your entire call stack to use it all the way up to the point where the framework called the starting point of your code.

Comment: @hkguile like Scott says, `string token = await ws.getToken(...)`

Comment: @hkguile are you firing this login request from a button event in winforms? if so you need to make that event async: `public async void Login_Button_Click(EventArgs e)`